# How do I grab the text and formatting from a PDF table with PDFBox?

Tags: c#, pdfbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing PDF files (especially with tables) with PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203790/parsing-pdf-files-especially-with-tables-with-pdfbox)

I am using PDFBox to parse out text using C# from a PDF file.  That works fine, but when the parser comes across a table, it parses out the text and destroys the formatting.

How can I parse text from a table but keep the formatting?