# Parsing a PDF File with empty fields in Java

Tags: java, parsing, pdf

I want to get Data out of a table in a PDF File.
I managed to extract the pdf to text with PDFBox or iText.

But the problem is that there are some empty fields in this table, but you can't find this in the extracted Text Files. It's really important to determine whether the fields are full or not.

Do anyone know how to manage that?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what is extracted? Are the empty fields simply missing from the extracted text? Do they have titles/headers that would enable you to detect what is present and what is missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=extract+table+pdf

Comment: ok i will try out this now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203790/parsing-pdf-files-especially-with-tables-with-pdfbox